# How to use @FileUpload.GetHtml inside Html.BeginForm and sumbit FilesList

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

There is a default submit button for the @FileUpload.GetHtml. But I am expecting to have a submit button inside the Html begin form and use that substitution to submit the list of files with some more parameters. But when I do that the passing IEnumerable is always null in the Action method.

This is my Action method:
    [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Change(IEnumerable filesList, Guid ID, string Btn)
        {....

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Change", "Home",FormMethod.Post))
    {
      <textarea id="textArea" name="epost2" class="frm_txtfield_big" style="float:left; width:638px; height:200px;"></textarea>

      <input type="hidden" name="supportID" value="@Model.ID" />

      @FileUpload.GetHtml(name: "ChooseFile",initialNumberOfFiles: 1,allowMoreFilesToBeAdded: true,includeFormTag: false)

      .......}
```

But this is not passing the list of files to the method.

Am doing it wrong or what is the wrong with the code.

Comment: FileUpload is server control of asp.net webforms. It is not about asp.net mvc. Are you sure that you use right tag?

Comment: Well I have seen of these in some tutorials as well. And the view is giving exactly what I was expecting. But its not submitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not included the `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` inside the `Html.BeginForm` So that the value is not taken to the file input. Now it ok.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4526286/892788) will give you a good explanation.