# How to use file upload?

Tags: c#, html, razor, file-upload

My fileupload isn't working. I get this error each time I try: `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index`.

I'm doing all of this from the `.cshtml` file because, the previous web master deleted all of the source code when he was fired. So I only have the deployed files to work with and none of the controllers and models. I also cannot add any new functionality to the website.

I used this tutorial [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/data/working-with-files#letting-users-upload-a-file) following the single file upload.

Here is my code:

```
@using Microsoft.Web.Helpers;
@{
    Layout="~/Views/Shared/_FUllWidthLayout.cshtml";

    var message="";
    if(IsPost){
        if(Request.Files.Count > 0){ //<-- If more than 0 files, FAILS HERE
            try{
                var uploadedFile = Request.Files[0];  //<-- FAILS HERE
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);
                var fileSavePath = Server.MapPath("~/Documents/Jobs/" + fileName);
                uploadedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
                message = Request.Files.Count + " files uploaded to " + fileSavePath;
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                message = e.Message;
            }
        }else{
            message = Request.Files.Count + " files uploaded.";
        }
    }
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<form id="uploadForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h3>FileUpload - Single-File Example</h3>
    <div class="inline-div">
        @FileUpload.GetHtml(
            initialNumberOfFiles:1,
            allowMoreFilesToBeAdded:false,
            includeFormTag:true,
            uploadText:"Upload")

        <small class="red">@message</small>
    </div>
</form>
```

I also tried taking the FileUpload control out of the form like this:

```
<h3>FileUpload - Single-File Example</h3>
<div class="inline-div">
    @FileUpload.GetHtml(
        initialNumberOfFiles:1,
        allowMoreFilesToBeAdded:false,
        includeFormTag:true,
        uploadText:"Upload")
    <small class="red">@message</small>
</div>
```

Message says "0 files uploaded." as seen here: [image]

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it? Or is there another tool I can use to do the same work?

Comment: You should check  Request.Files before accessing index 0 with `Request.Files[0];`

Comment: My apologies, I was doing that before, but I wanted to capture the actual error.

Comment: It might be worthwhile for you to inspect `Request.Files` to see it's structure / content in debugger.

Comment: You have `includeFormTag: true`, but are wrapping the control in a `form` tag. If I'm not mistaken, you want `includeFormTag: false` if you're going to be providing the `form` tag yourself.

Comment: I get the same result whether I place the fileupload control inside a form or not.

Comment: Have you tried including a form tag as in your first example, but set `includeFormTag` to false? See for example [How to use @FileUpload.GetHtml inside Html.BeginForm and sumbit FilesList](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12282988/215552)

Comment: Yes, I've tried that as well. Actually, that was the very first way I tried it.